# Spring MVC unit tests - param Date

Tags: spring, junit, parameters

I have this problem to pass a Date in junit.

I try to pass param dateFrom as String, because as Date is imposible but then i can execute this method because system try to map a Date with a string. Thats the problem.

this is my method in junit.

```
this.mockMvc
            .perform(
                    get("/findElement/ajax/makeAction").header("Accept", "*/*").sessionAttr(Constants.DATA, this.data)
                            .param("index", "")
                            .param("numElems", "50")
                            .param("dateFrom", "2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"))
                            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

}

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/makeAction", headers = "Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Liquidacion> consultaMasLiquidaciones(User user, Product product)
```

where product has product.dateFrom

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it was very simple

.param("dateFrom", "22/09/2015")

Maybe you have to test different formats of string to parse to date.

Thanks